# Test controller setup with VisualStudioOnline

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm unable to configure a test controller with a visualStudioOnline server. Normally, when logging into VSO you are prompted with a login screen. When adding the server in the test controller configuration, this login screen is displayed but immediately closed and adding the VSO server fails. Any Ideas?

Update: It works just fine if the user name to "Logon account for test controller service" is the same user that has premissions to install a controller on VSO. Unfortunately "Use different credentials to connect to Team Foundation Server" does not work and is greyed out if the accounts are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing visual studio (same year version), added the server via VS and was able to complete the signin prompt in VS. When adding the controllor, the servers popped up with no prompt, allowing me to select the servers.

Comment: thanks, +1, I had the same issue and ended up using the same trick, worked fine for me too. Tough the solution is kinda hacky, your post saved me hours.